# JavaのオブジェクトをシリアライズしてC#でデシリアライズしたい

Tags: java, c#, xml

Javaで生成したオブジェクトをシリアライズして標準入出力を介してC#に渡してデシリアライズしたいです。

シリアライズ、デシリアライズしたいクラスは以下のようなものです。

```
class Member
{
public String Name;
public String Email;
}

class Group
{
public String Name;
pubilc String Email;
public List &lt;Member&gt; Members;
}
```

上記クラスでのList<Group>をJava,C#間で受け渡ししたいです。
オブジェクトをシリアライズ、デシリアライズするには
XMLやYAMLといった形式があるみたいです。
しかしどのライブラリを使うかによって同じXMLやYAMLでも微妙に形式の違いがあるようです。
JavaのオブジェクトをC#で再生するにはJava側、C#側それぞれで
どのライブラリの組み合わせを使えば一番うまくいくでしょうか。

クラスになにも手を加えないでJavaのオブジェクトをC#で再現できるのが一番ですが、
必要ならばクラスをHashMapに変換する程度の手間は許容できます。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java側にSimple、C#側に`XmlSerializer`を使用するのが良いかと思います。
ただし要素名/属性名が大文字と小文字でぶれますので、JavaアノテーションもしくはC#カスタム属性で統一してやる必要があります。通常はJava側で

```
@Root(name = "Group")
public class Group {

    @Element(name = "Name")
    public String Name;

    @Element(name = "Email")
    public String Email;

    @ElementList(name = "Members")
    public List<Member> Members;

}

@Root(name = "Member")
public class Member {

    @Element(name = "Name")
    public String Name;

    @Element(name = "Email")
    public String Email;

}
```

と各アノテーションの`name`を明示してやればよいです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
SimpleとXmlSerializerでは微妙に仕様が違うらしく(Listの扱いなど)
一発変換とはいきませんでしたが正規表現とか使ってちょろっと
いじってやれば変換できそうです。

Comment: @Jogenara 追記したJava側定義を使用すれば.NETのデフォルト動作と一致すると思います

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Listの展開の仕様が微妙に違ったのですがinline=trueを指定することで一致させられました。

Comment: @Jogenara こちらで確認したところ、回答の定義で属性2か所をのぞいてXMLが一致していました。`inline=true`を指定すると要素の階層が`/Group/Members/Member`から`/Group/Member`になってしまう気がします。いずれにせよ動いているのであればそれで問題はないと思いますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。XmlSerializerの仕様がちがうんですかね？
C#のほうは/Group/Members/Member ではなく /Group/Member の形式でしたのでjavaのほうでListをinlineしました。
こちら<GroupList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
となっていますが、たぶんこれが変換ルールなんですよね？
これからなにかわかることありますでしょうか。

Comment: @Jogenara シリアライズしている要素自体が`Group`と`GroupList`で異なるように見えます

Comment: 後出しですいません。もともとList<Group>をシリアライズ化したかったのですが、
List<Group>をそのままシリアライズする方法がわからずGroupListというクラスを追加してます。
でもGroupの構造は変えてないので/Group/Members/Memberか/Group/Memberかには影響ないと思います。

Comment: すいません。C#で

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("member")]
List<Member> Members{get;set;}

とすべきところを

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("member")]
List<Member> Members{get;set;}

としていたのが階層が合わなかった原因みたいです。

Comment: @Jogenara 原因が判明したようで何よりです